# Can't use "var" variables in the .ascx?

Tags: c#, .net

On .ascx.cs I have this code, for example :

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or XDocument.Load(fileName)
var list =  xDoc.Descendants("ordinanza")
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    Numero = n.Element("numero").Value,
                    Titolo = n.Element("titolo").Value,
                })
                .ToList();
```

Well, now I'd like to "foreach" this anonymous type on my .ascx, but I can't use protected/public for `list` (because is `var`).

So, how can I do it?

Comment: How do you want to "`foreach`" it on the ascx markup? Why don't you do that in codebehind?

Comment: Because I need to write HTML code due to data in that custQuery. I hate write HTML into string/string builder...

Comment: But the normal ASP.NET way would be to use a webdatabound control like repeater and don't generate html but put controls(f.e. custom UserControls) in an `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : can you give to me an example using `var` as `source data` for a Repeater?

Comment: It's not a problem to bind an anonymous type to a web-databound control like Repeater or GridView. You don't even need to call `ToList()`. For example: `repeater.DataSource = xDoc.Descendants("ordinanza")
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    Numero = n.Element("numero").Value,
                    Titolo = n.Element("titolo").Value,
                });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you're extracting is a cut-down version of a larger entity, and you're using this data in a view.  This in MVC or MVP terms would be a view model (a type of data transfer object for displaying data in the UI).

What you could do is create a simple lightweight class (view model) to hold this data:

```
public CustomerContactViewModel()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

and then update your LINQ query to:

```
IEnumerable<CustomerContactViewModel> custQuery =
    from cust in customers
    where cust.City == "Phoenix"
    select new CustomerContactViewModel() { Name = cust.Name, Phone = cust.Phone };
```

Comment: Yeah...but the use of "var" is vanished :)

Comment: Isn't that a good thing? :-)  In terms of the problem you specify being "I can't pass around anonymous objects between methods and expect them to behave like strongly typed objects", my solution is "pass around strongly typed objects".

Comment: Use "var" is useful! Also, if I can use it with a Repeater (as Tim Schmelter suggest) would be nice, isn't it?

Comment: If you are binding to your collection of anonymous types then the use of `var` is fine.  But if you wish to pass the collection between methods there might be problems.  It depends on your usage really when using collections of anonymous types.  They're best short lived.

Comment: Don't think var is what you're looking for then. Seems like you want a dynamic object instead.